# Modal div goes off screen using position absolute and top % with small window height

Tags: css

I have a modal div:

```
<div class = "modal"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -325px; /* centered horizontally */
  top: 48%; 
  margin-top: -250px; /* centered (almost) vertically */
  width: 650px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

The problem is, if the browser window's height is too small, the div goes off the screen at the top. You can scroll down and see the rest, but the top bit begins to hide.

Is there anyway to set the % to px if the browser window is a certain height? Or perhaps there is a better solution to this.

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9cga0629/

Comment: Looks like the top bit still hides in that fiddle.

Comment: Looks like it yeah, with a bit of padding between the top border and div obviously. I'm not that good with CSS so a lot of that is confusing.